# IndexError: 'too many indices for array' for numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
np_data =  np.array([['WORKING', '32398', 'PATTERN', '1\n'],
                     ['SUBMIT', ' 12398', 'CHECKSUM', '1\n']], dtype=object)
col1 = np_data[:, 1]
```

got error : IndexError: 'too many indices for array'

```
np_data.shape
```

o/p : (2,)

```
np_data[0][0]
np_data[1][0]
```

o/p:
   WORKING, 
   SUBMIT

Any solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your error... Are you sure you posted the right values?

Comment: yes even I am confused Actually I am parsing csv files for somefiles it executes correctly but for some it gives the error.

Comment: Creating an array from the display produces a (2,2) array, containing strings as objects, but the error indicates it actually is a 2 element array containing two lists. The arrays may look the same, but the creation methods will be different.

Comment: Some lines of the files have different numbers of columns.

Comment: If that's the case, maybe you should check the shape of your array before accessing it.

Comment: I have this same issue. I have created this with `np.array(Q(query), dtype = result_dtype)`  where Q returns a 2 block of values which has a shape of `(1323,)` the result_type is `[('timestamp','i4'), ('host', 'U60'),('port','i2'),('slice','i4'),('any','f4'),('avg','f4'),('max','f4'),('min','f4')]` to match the data types. It can address the cells like this `rows[1][1]` but will cause the error the OP sees if i do `rows[0][1:]`